# Where should I ask questions that are related to web portals that can be accessed by administrators?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

For example, [this Q&A](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/112582/128573) has been posted on the web application Stack Exchange site, but one of the users wonders whether this is on topic.

Comment: That is a discussion for the local meta. Why are you asking here?

Comment: In theory, its a broader site request. Its only in practice that it turns out the right site is the one he's on ;p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no actual closevotes. I see a comment, and what feels like a wrong assumption. Office 365 in *this context* is a webapp and it feels on topic where it is.

Comment: There is one closevote "off-topic", you would need 3K on that site to see it.

Comment: This certainly seems on-topic for [webapps.se] to me.